# Vue RouterLink error: Cannot destructure property 'options' of 'vue.inject()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am migrating a codebase from vue 2 to vue 3 and making some good progress. I have been stuck on an issue with `vue-router` and I am not sure how to resolve it. I am currently using `@vue/compat` and [walking through the installation guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html#installation).

The problem is tied to `<router-link>` whenever I use it, I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'options' of 'vue.inject(...)' as it is undefined.

    at setup (.../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.cjs.js:2138)
    at callWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:123)
    at setupStatefulComponent (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:1242)
    at setupComponent (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:1238)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:838)
    at processComponent (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:834)
    at patch (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:755)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:856)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:67)
    at setupRenderEffect (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:881)
```

The error is preceded with some warnings as well:

```
// 3 of:
[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.

// and 1 of:
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. 
    This is likely a Vue internals bug. 
    Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core
    (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js?ebac:120)
```

I have stripped the `main.js` down to:

```
import { createApp, configureCompat } from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './main.css'

// some font awesome icon & vue-fontawesome imports/registration as well
 
configureCompat({
    MODE: 3
})

createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(store)
    .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
    .mount('#app')
```

Here is my router:

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import Module from '@/components/Framework/Module'
import Dashboard from "@/views/Dashboard"

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'dashboard', 
            component: Dashboard
        },
    ]
})

export default router
```

Comment: Does your code explicitly use `inject()` somewhere? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: It does not—the `inject()` is happening inside of `vue-router`.

Comment: I figured this out—it was a webpack whitelisting issue.